# Google Analytics, remarketing and GDPR

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

after reading tons of stuff about the GDPR i have got that we have to dinamically load google analytics code and remarketing code after the user has formally expressed his consent (no matter what settings you choose for your analytics, google in its policy ask us to do so, so we have to do it).

I'm trying to prepare a simple scripts to dinamically load google analytics code and remarketing code after the user accept that.

Can you tell me if there are any problem with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="Just a test page" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <script>
function processScripts(){
    analytics();    
    remarketing();
}

function analytics(){
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-YOUR_UA-YOUR_VIEW', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
    ga('send', 'pageview'); 
}

function remarketing(){
    google_conversion_id = YOUR_CONVERSION_ID;
    google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
    google_remarketing_only = true; 

    var d = document,
        h = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        s = d.createElement('script');

    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = '//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js';
    h.appendChild(s);
}
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p><a href="" onclick="processScripts();return false;">Accept</a></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This should be okay. Did you face any problem?

Comment: at the moment the only real problem is this one

"È stata ignorata una chiamata a document.write() eseguita da uno script esterno caricato in modalità asincrona.
conversion.js:31:374"

Sorry it is in italian but it translates to "A call to document.write () was ignored by an external script loaded asynchronously."

This means that the conversion.js used for the remarketing tag has some problems i think.

Comment: Naturally this doesn't happen if you call the script properly by pasting its code at the end of the html page, before the body tag

Comment: For anyone else not using remarketing or GA's 'Data Collection for Advertising Features', then you don't need to ask for consent.